# How to make one collection using three collections?

Tags: c#, linq

I want to make one collection of three according to certain conditions (with LINQ). let's say I have a Class:

```
class Collection
{
  public int id;
  public string name;
  public double weight;
}
```

Then I'm creating collections:

```
List<Collection> collection1 = new()
{
  new Collection() { id = 11, name = "Abraham 1", weight = 1.1 },
  new Collection() { id = 12, name = "Abraham 2", weight = 1.2 },
  new Collection() { id = 13, name = "Abraham 3", weight = 1.3 },
};

List<Collection> collection2 = new()
{
  new Collection() { id = 21, name = "Bill 1", weight = 2.1 },
  new Collection() { id = 22, name = "Bill 2", weight = 2.2 },
  new Collection() { id = 23, name = "Bill 3", weight = 2.3 },
};

List<Collection> collection3 = new()
{
  new Collection() { id = 31, name = "David 1", weight = 3.1 },
  new Collection() { id = 32, name = "David 2", weight = 3.2 },
  new Collection() { id = 33, name = "David 3", weight = 3.3 },
};
```

TODO 1. Condition: get 1st column from 1st collection, 2nd column from 2nd collection, 3rd column from 3rd column.  result should be:

```
{
  new Collection() { id = 11, name = "Bill 1", weight = 3.1 },
  new Collection() { id = 12, name = "Bill 2", weight = 3.2 },
  new Collection() { id = 13, name = "Bill 3", weight = 3.1 }
}
```

TODO 2. Second case condition: get first elements from columns of all collections. result should be:

```
{
  new Collection() { id = 11, name = "Abraham 1", weight = 1.1 },
  new Collection() { id = 21, name = "Bill 1", weight = 2.1 },
  new Collection() { id = 31, name = "David 1", weight = 3.1 }
}
```

Please help.

Comment: I shall be the first to say this: huh?

Comment: Your question contains insufficient information. Why can't you just use `if (condition) result = ??? else result = ???`

Comment: There's no indication in your question how you get your 2 different results. Even if you can't put it in to code you should easily be able to describe the requirements

Comment: Why is an instance of a list called `Collection`? It's a single item, not a collection! Anyway, even with the edit of your actual list objects, it's not clear why result 1 and result 2 should be created. You've failed to specify the logic behind this grouping.

Comment: And your conditions are????

Comment: first case condition: get first column from 1st collection, second column from second collection, 3rd column from therd column.
second case condition: get first elements vrom columns of all collections

Comment: Each collection always have the same amount of members? Update those to the question, not in comments

Comment: Please edit your question to explain this, rather than replying with a comment.

Comment: Also, note that if you want the first from first,  second from second, third from third, then your first example is wrong as you have David x3.

Comment: You've edited your question, but why does your second case contain Bill 1, Bill 2, and Bill 3? That seems to be all entries from the second collection, and not what you describe.

Comment: now questions and descriptions matching.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using C# 10 and .Net 6, just use `Enumerable.Zip`:

```
var todo1 = collection1.Zip(collection2, collection3)
                       .Select(t => new Collection { id = t.First.id, name = t.Second.name, weight = t.Third.weight })
                       .ToList();

var todo2 = collection1.Zip(collection2, collection3)
                       .Select(t => new List<Collection> { t.First, t.Second, t.Third })
                       .First();
```

If you don't have the three argument `Zip` that returns a tuple, just roll your own, e.g. for Todo1:

```
var td1 = collection1.Zip(collection2, (c1, c2) => (c1, c2))
                     .Zip(collection3, (t12, c3) => (First: t12.c1, Second: t12.c2, Third: c3))
                     .Select(t => new Collection { id = t.First.id, name = t.Second.name, weight = t.Third.weight })
                     .ToList();
```

Answer (score -2):

If you want to merge multiple collections into one collection using LINQ then do this:

```
List<Collection> result = collection1.Concat(collection2).OrderBy(x => x.id).ToList();
```

Comment: And if the `id` values for `collection1` were `17,12,23`?